# How to Write AZURE Easy TABLE Script with Join Operation

Tags: node.js, azure-mobile-services

I am facing problem in writing Azure Easy Table Script.
In read function i am performing select operation to fetch the data from TWO different table. I am also performing JOIN operation in that select query.

Please Help.

Help Appreciated.

Code Snippet is given Below :

```
todoFetchQuery = "SELECT todo.*,abc.firstName ,abc.middleName, abc.lastName from Todo LEFT OUTER JOIN student ON (todo.to_id = abc.id) where tea_id = '" + context.req.query.teaRecordId + "'";
```

Comment: You have not provided enough information.  What are you trying to do?  Where are you trying to do it?  What does the complete code look like?  What error message are you getting?  What isn't working for you?

Comment: @AdrianHall  Hello Sir, I am writing this code in todo.js(table). I am not getting any error message.This code is working properly but only problem is that i am getting data of todo table (todo.*) not of abc table(abc.firstName).

Comment: @AdrianHall  Code :
var todotable = module.exports = require('azure-mobile-apps').table();
var abcTable = module.exports = require('azure-mobile-apps').table("abc");
module.exports = todotable;

todotable.read(function (context) {  
  todoFetchQuery = "SELECT todo.*,abc.firstName ,abc.middleName, abc.lastName from Todo LEFT OUTER JOIN student ON (todo.to_id = abc.id) where tea_id = '" + context.req.query.teaRecordId + "'";
  context.execute(alertFetchQuery)
        .then(function (results) {
        context.res.status(200).json(results);
    });
};

Comment: That won't work.  I'll reply with an answer as to the proper method.

Comment: You can try to use middleware in Easy Tables, you can refer to the answer of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36190191/azure-mobile-app-node-js-backend-custom-queries-and-passing-parameters/36192066#36192066

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to do what you want is to create an SQL VIEW that is the combination of the tables.  See the following for a walk-through of using an existing SQL table and a view that supports all the fields necessary.  https://adrianhall.github.io/develop-mobile-apps-with-csharp-and-azure/chapter3/server/#using-an-existing-sql-table

In your case, you create the view that shows your data - once the view works, you can just use a regular table controller that is using the view instead of the table to project into Azure Mobile Apps client SDKs and everything will "just work".

Comment: Isn't it possible to write " Raw SQL Join Query " in Standard Read Function ?